# Mudar texto do span ao clicar

Tags: jquery

Eu criei essa função para que quando fosse clicada, mostrar as etiquetas dos posts. Ela funciona normalmente, mas eu gostaria de mudar o texto "open tags" para "hide tags" quando ele fosse clicado, como faço isso?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".notec").click(function(){
        $(".t").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.t{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags">
                         
    <span class="notec">open tags</span>

    <div class="t">
        <a href="/">tag 1</a>
        <a href="/">tag 2</a>
        <a href="/">tag 3</a>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi. Você pode pegar o texto que está aparecendo no `span` usando `$(this).text()` dentro do evento de `click`. Depois basta verificar se o valor do texto é `"open tags"` ou `"hide tags"` e mudar. Para alterar o texto é só usar `$(this).text("Novo Texto")`.

Segue o código funcionado:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".notec").click(function(){
        $(".t").slideToggle();
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (text == "open tags") {
          $(this).text("hide tags");
        } else {
          $(this).text("open tags");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.t{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags">
                         
    <span class="notec">open tags</span>

    <div class="t">
        <a href="/">tag 1</a>
        <a href="/">tag 2</a>
        <a href="/">tag 3</a>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ajudou bastante, obrigada!!